# Swift - Date from components is incorrect when printed. Date has 2 values?

Tags: swift, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to store a time of day in a Date:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.init(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.hour = 7
components.minute = 0

var newDate = calendar?.date(from: components as DateComponents)!

print(newDate!)
```

However, this yields some bizarre results when I try to print or otherwise use the value. Here's a Swift Playground of the results:

[image: Strange date results]

How can `newDate` be both 7:00AM and 11:56AM at the same time?

Comment: FYI - Using a `Date` to store just a time in hours and minutes is a bad idea. What do you really need to do with your "time of day"?

Comment: Also note that the playground shows `Date` objects in local time and when you `print` a `Date`, the date value is shown in UTC time. So unless you live in UTC time, you will always see two different times. But this case is more unusual since the difference is normally whole or half hours depending on your timezone. This case is most likely due to the year being 1 and not a more modern year.

Comment: worth mentioning that you should be using `DateComponent` instead of `NSDateComponent` and `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar` since Swift3

Comment: To reiterate rmaddy's point, "I'm trying to store a time of day in a Date" means that you're using `Date` incorrectly. Don't do that. If you want to store "time on a clock" then store 2-3 Ints (hour, minute, second). If you want to store "seconds since most recent midnight," then store that (remembering that this is *not* the same thing as hours/minutes/seconds since there may be DST changes).

Comment: There's been no Gregorian calendar (yet) at year 1 AD  Everything before 1582 is unspecified.

Comment: @vadian For `NSCalendar`, it is well-specified: [“`NSCalendar` models the behavior of a proleptic Gregorian calendar (as defined by ISO 8601:2004), which extends the Gregorian calendar backward in time from the date of its introduction.”](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar)

Comment: @robmayoff I know, I was kidding a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify a time zone (by setting the `timeZone` property of either `components` or `calendar`). So the system used your local time zone to convert `components` to a date.

The playground system used your local time zone to convert `newDate` to the string “Jan 1, 1 at 7:00 AM”. (The playground system has special-case code for displaying `Date` objects. The special-case code uses your local time zone.)

The `print` function used the UTC time zone to convert `newDate` to the string “0001-01-01 11:56:02 +0000”.  (The `print` function uses the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol. `Date`'s `CustomStringConvertible` implementation uses the UTC time zone.)

I deduce that your local time zone is US/Eastern time, also known as `America/New_York`:

```
import Foundation

var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.hour = 7
components.minute = 0

for timeZoneIdentifier in TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers {
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timeZoneIdentifier)!
    let date = calendar.date(from: components as DateComponents)!
    let dateString = "\(date)"
    if dateString == "0001-01-01 11:56:02 +0000" {
        print("\(timeZoneIdentifier) \(date)")
    }
}
// Only one line of output: America/New_York 0001-01-01 11:56:02 +0000
```

**So why the weird minutes and seconds in UTC?**  [Because at noon on November 18, 1883, the US and Canada railway companies began using a new, standard time system](http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/d.html), which is the time system we still use today. Observe:

```
import Foundation

let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()

var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/New_York")!
let components = NSDateComponents()

components.year = 1883
components.month = 11
components.day = 18

components.hour = 11
print(formatter.string(from: calendar.date(from: components as DateComponents)!))
// prints 1883-11-18T15:56:02Z

components.hour = 12
print(formatter.string(from: calendar.date(from: components as DateComponents)!))
// prints 1883-11-18T17:00:00Z
```

Prior to noon, the difference from UTC time is 4:56:02.

Before the advent of standard railway time, we typically defined local time based on local apparent noon (the moment when the sun is highest in the sky and shadows point exactly north or south or disappear entirely if the sun is directly overhead).

If we look at the definition of America/New_York in [the tz Time Zone Database](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/northamerica), we find this:

```
# From Paul Eggert (2014-09-06):
# Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society 44, 4 (1884-02-08), 208
# says that New York City Hall time was 3 minutes 58.4 seconds fast of
# Eastern time (i.e., -4:56:01.6) just before the 1883 switch.  Round to the
# nearest second.
```

and a bit further down:

```
Zone America/New_York   -4:56:02 -  LMT 1883 Nov 18 12:03:58
```

This explains the difference we see above prior to noon on November 18, 1883.

Comment: I understand this but.. so how can I print the right time?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by “right time”. You should probably post your own question with full details.

Comment: So I realized after this that... print does not change the actual value but it only displays the value in a different time zone. I just got confused when the answer said print  "converts". `print` does not actually change the value but only displays it in UTC. Now I get it.