# Time output not as expected when using iOS SDK DateFormatter on Date set to Jan 1, 1

Tags: ios, swift, date, timezone

I have a scenario where dates are being on a server without the day aspect and just the time is needed. Therefore the day element is being stripped away before uploading to the server. Development up to this point (Point 1 in code below) cannot be changed as it is coming from an external source that is already in production.

We are then facing an issue when outputting this time back to the user. The time varies by minutes in different locations, even in the same timezone. Please check the code with comments below.

```
//1.
//Taking a date with just hours and minutes as I don't need the date.
//The timezone set (Europe/Rome) is different from the machine (Europe/Malta)
//Issue below still occurs if we use the same timezone as the machine.
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 1570168800) //Result: Oct 4, 2050 at 8:00 AM

var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Rome")!
let comps = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)

let strippedDate = calendar.date(from: comps)! //Result: Jan 1, 1 at 8:08 AM
//the date outputted is bypassing the timezone setting and using the machine timezone when stripping out the day
//and keeping hours and minutes alone

//2.
//Outputing the date back to the user in different timezone identifiers
//These timezone identiers are all in the same timezone
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short;

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")!
var formattedStart = dateFormatter.string(from: strippedDate) //Result: "7:19 AM"

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Rome")!
formattedStart = dateFormatter.string(from: strippedDate) //Result: "8:00 AM"
//This above appears correctly as it's coming from the same timezone that set up the starting date

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Malta")! 
formattedStart = dateFormatter.string(from: strippedDate) //Result: "8:08 AM"
//The above appears the same as the stripped date which is the same as the machine used to create the stripped date

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Madrid")!
formattedStart = dateFormatter.string(from: strippedDate) //Result: "6:55 AM"
```

Referencing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700657/1187532), this issue is happening "Because at noon on November 18, 1883, the US and Canada railway companies began using a new, standard time system". Therefore since the date is being saved before this event, this might be the reason why we're getting varied minutes. However I still cannot find a solution to output the correct time.

Comment: On the server we have dates stored in ISO format like this 0001-01-03T07:01:56.000Z. Then we have an API that converts these back to dates in swift. The result is exactly like the strippedDate above, which is why I didn't include server-related functionality in the code above because the problem happens with our without a server. Therefore what we need is a way to get the hours and minutes from the strippedDate back to how they were in date above, which seems to work fine when you're using the same timezone identifier but varies with different timezone identifiers.